# How to Configure MySQL to be Case Sensitive

Tags: mysql

What are the commands to enable and disable case sensitivity by default for an entire database on a MySQL server? I'm aware of the [COLLATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html) statement, but it seems it's necessary to place this in every SQL statement that's run. Is there an option to set this globally?

Comment: what's the context? e.g. language you're working on?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can set collation at both the database creation and table creation level as a part of the [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) statement.

To set the collation for the entire database, you can use:

```
CREATE DATABASE test_database CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_cs;
```

You can also change the collation on an existing database via ALTER DATABASE. (For more information see the MySQL [Database Character Set and Collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-database.html) manual entry.)

If however, only a single table needs to be treated as case sensitive, you could simply use:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table;
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  test_id bigint unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  ...

  PRIMARY KEY test_id (test_id),
  ...
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_cs;
```

(Case insensitive being "`utf8_general_ci`".)

Finally, the main MySQL [Character Set Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset.html) manual section is probably worth a quick peruse. (It lists the [character sets and collations supported by MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-charsets.html), tells you how to s[et the character set/collation at the server level](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-server.html), etc.)

Comment: Alternatively `utf8_bin` is also commonly used.

Comment: @Unode Yup, utf8_bin doesn't equate "á" to "a", etc.

Comment: Coupled to what @middaparka said and my previous comment, you should be careful about sorting since accentuated characters may not always sort the way you expect them to. However most of these issues are related to specific encodings and locale settings. (beyond the scope of this question)

Comment: Error Code: 1273
Unknown collation: 'utf8_general_cs'

Comment: @Chris Ah my bad - that might not be available in your build of MySQL - I'd recommend using "utf8_bin" for now.

Comment: I've tried both `ALTER DATABASE mydb CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;` and `ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;` but when I run `select first_name from mydb.mytable where first_name = 'joe2'` it still shows "Joe2", indicating it's search is still case-insensitive. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Chris If it's an existing table, you might need to alter the field collation. Alternatively, you could try adding "COLLATE utf8_bin" to the end of your query as a temporary fix. (See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html for more info.)

Comment: @Cerin Ooo... you just changed name. Hmm... I'm really working for my "accepted answer" on this one, but fingers crossed it's sorted for you now. :-)

Answer (score 6):

I've come here looking to modify the collation only for a specific column for it to be case-sensitive and not for the entire table or the database. Hope it helps someone looking just for this.

This query could be tried:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name column_datatype COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Comment: I added this and it works - there are limitations for the column_datatype like VARCHAR limits < 300 lengths

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to create a MySQL database with case-sensitive collation is:

```
CREATE DATABASE your_db_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Comment: I'm getting `ERROR 1273 (HY000): Unknown collation: 'utf8'`

Comment: Do you mean uft8_bin (with an underscore)?