# Mysql disable international string comparison

Tags: mysql, encoding, globalization

I've got a problem with returning data from MySql database.
I have table which have been populated with data such as:

```
ID,Name
1,India
2,Índia
```

Whenever i make

```
select * from table where Name='India'
```

it keeps returning both records. I've read comment on MySql documentation page which says:

> Also, keep in mind that by default,
>   Swedish/Finnish string comparison rules are in
>   use! This means that e.g.: u <> ü = y !

I guess it might be the same case. Could someone help me out with disabling this feature? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [important documentation that could help you?](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html) At least, I hope so.

Answer (score 0):

[this seems pretty and useful!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879846/how-to-configure-mysql-to-be-case-sensitive) =)

Just to one column:

```
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY Name varchar2 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Comment: I have .net core application using mysql so i'd like to make change on database to avoid ingering into .net core mysql provider (many features are in beta state and we are close to deadline and i don't want whole application to collapse)