# Case sensitive issue when making login in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code used to check login details. Specially to check password from user entered data and data in SQL.

```
if ($request->input('password') != $fromUser[0]->Password) {
    $currentStatus = "invalid_password";
  }
```

This code works well in my local machine. Checking case sensitive too. It mean when `"$request->input('password')" = "DemoTest" and "$fromUser[0]->Password" = "demotest"`,
 it's not matching and `return false ($currentStatus = "invalid_password";)`.

But when I hosted this on server, this is not working. Not checking case sensitive and if above condition happened, it gives me true.
Why is that ? I hosted this in Windows server. But my local machine is Linux.

Comment: _"I hosted this in Windows server. But my local machine is Linux."_ this is your answer.

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos What ? :) Can you please explain me

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos Is there any code or library i can use to fix this ?

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive)

Comment: More specifically for the data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879846/how-to-configure-mysql-to-be-case-sensitive)

Comment: Also, use password hashing for storing passwords, and not storing them in plain text, which is a major security flaw. http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php or for lavarel specifically: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/hashing

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are dealing with Password then you need to use **Hash** code to store the password in DB and use **strcmp** to password match.
Try like this

```
$var1=Hash::make($var1);
if(strcmp($var1, $var2) != 0) {
    $currentStatus = "invalid_password";
 }
```

I thing it will work for you.