# JPQL- Case sensitive string comparison

Tags: jpa, jpql

Does anyone know how to have case-sensitive comparison of 2 strings at a JPQL Query?

PS. I don't want to use Native Query so that's why I ask.

Thank You.

Comment: I think that I told that I want to do case sensitive comparison, not insensitive comparison

Comment: Case sensitive string comparison is the default. Please provide a more specific case where it's not working for you, otherwise we won't be able to help

Comment: I have a jpql query like this SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.password = :password and for example password is abcd there is no difference if I put to the parameter the value abcd the value ABcd etc. so you understand that there is a safety problem

Comment: I don't think you should be seeing this behavior. Which JPA provider? Are you sure the `:password` parameter is not converted to a different case *before* being used in the query? Could this be a db issue? Be advised that some versions of db servers (most notably SQL Server) perform case-insensitive comparisons by default, and case sensitivity needs to be explicitly enabled

Comment: You are right probably it’s the default of MySQL workbench. How can I turn on case sensitivity on MySQL workbench?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879846/how-to-configure-mysql-to-be-case-sensitive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Configure MySQL to be Case Sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879846/how-to-configure-mysql-to-be-case-sensitive)